# Change the y limits ( especially the minimum) with Vlnplot

Tags: r, violin-plot, seurat

I would like to draw a violin plot from my single cell data.

I am using this function :

```
Vlnplot(object, features, cols = NULL, pt.size = 0.1)
```

But I would like to change the y axis to 3000-10000 instead of 0-70000.

They only propose to change the y max but not the mean

Does someone have an idea how to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `VlnPlot` function in the `Seurat` R package uses `ggplot2` to draw the violin plot. This means we can modify the y-axis using `scale_y_continuous`.

In your case, to change the y-axis of your violin plot to 3000-10000, we would write:

```
VlnPlot(object, features, cols = NULL, pt.size = 0.1) + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(3000,10000))
```

To show you a reproducible example, we can draw a violin plot using the `pbmc_small` dataset from the `Seurat` package:

```
VlnPlot(pbmc_small, "CD3E")
```

[image: default violin plot]

The plot above has a default axis of 0 to around 6.3. Here is how the same plot looks like after altering the y-axis using `scale_y_continuous`, in which I zoom in between 0 and 3:

```
VlnPlot(pbmc_small, "CD3E") + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,3))
```

[image: violin plot after changing axis]

Many of the other visualizations in the `Seurat` package also use ggplot2, so you can make all types of cosmetic changes to them using various ggplot2 commands (themes, axis labels, colors, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for your help!